# Determine which marketplace a Sponsored Product belongs to - in Amazon Advertising API

Tags: amazon-advertising-api

Currently I am pulling reports for SponsoredProducts and save it in database for modifications of results displayed to the user. The frontend app has filtering functionality by marketplace. How do you determine which Marketplace a Sponsored Product belongs to? In Advertising api, there's no option to pass the marketplace id as parameters. Here is the example result from Advertising API

```
       {
    "sku": "DT-ALF3-XXX",
    "adId": 11308014834513628,
    "asin": "B07V3ZBJSXX",
    "cost": 0,
    "clicks": 0,
    "currency": "EUR",
    "adGroupId": 988845154306152,
    "campaignId": 253559015894968,
    "adGroupName": "halterung",
    "impressions": 0,
    "campaignName": "29.08.2019 - Breit",
    "attributedSales1d": 0,
    "attributedSales7d": 0,
    "attributedSales14d": 0,
    "attributedSales30d": 0,
    "attributedConversions1d": 0,
    "attributedConversions7d": 0,
    "attributedConversions14d": 0,
    "attributedConversions30d": 0,
    "attributedSales1dSameSKU": 0,
    "attributedSales7dSameSKU": 0,
    "attributedUnitsOrdered1d": 0,
    "attributedUnitsOrdered7d": 0,
    "attributedSales14dSameSKU": 0,
    "attributedSales30dSameSKU": 0,
    "attributedUnitsOrdered14d": 0,
    "attributedUnitsOrdered30d": 0,
    "attributedConversions1dSameSKU": 0,
    "attributedConversions7dSameSKU": 0,
    "attributedConversions14dSameSKU": 0,
    "attributedConversions30dSameSKU": 0,
    "attributedUnitsOrdered1dSameSKU": 0,
    "attributedUnitsOrdered7dSameSKU": 0,
    "attributedUnitsOrdered14dSameSKU": 0,
    "attributedUnitsOrdered30dSameSKU": 0
},
```

Regards,

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.Since the amazon advertising requires specific profile id in every request(the profile id is the id exclusive to a customer who gives permissions to a third party to fetch data from Amazon advertising api on their behalf), I just need to map the profile id's related marketplace by pulling the `/v2/profiles` end point in Amazon Advertising API